# How to power a Raspberry Pi and servo motors with one power supply

Tags: pi-3b+, power, servo, power-management

I'm building a robot using Raspberry Pi and several servo motors. I'd like to power all components using a single lithium ion battery. I've looked into using a motor driver hat, but it seems the motor hats are unable to power the pi, so two separate power sources are required. Can anyone provide advice on how to best achieve my goal of powering the pi and all motors from one power source? Thanks!

Comment: I just bought a RMB32, 220VAC to 12VDC 10A PSU to drive 10 servos. I am going to test it today. Leave me a comment if you wish me to update you on my servo powering experiment. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Use a 5V buck converter to feed power from your lithium ion battery to the Pi

https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-ubec-dc-dc-step-down-buck-converter-5v-3a-output

Comment: I use a 5V 4 amp UBEC I bought from eBay for £1.70.